# Undefined \printindex

Tags: errors, indexing

```
tex/.../supp-pdf.tex
tex/.../supp-mis.tex
loading : Context Support Macros / Miscellaneous (2004.10.26)
)
loading : Context Support Macros / PDF (2004.03.26)
)
tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.19 \printindex
 ?
```

I am getting this error right now. I googled and found in the same forum about this and it asked for `hyperref` package download.

As I am in HUB , I cannot access `hyperref` folder and but I can see hyper ref folder is already existing. I am using tetex(3.0)

I can see that while converting from latex to pdf , It is giving the compilation errors. Is there other ways to solve this. Or What are the other packages I need to to be installed .?

Comment: try `\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex` in the preamble of your document.

Comment: If I use makeidx and make index  .I dont get any compilation errors and not even PDF file. I am not getting the pdf file Iam looking for ,the pdf file is empty!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @knowit09: you have also to run the external program `makeindex` and then `pdflatex` again.

Comment: is it like  > makeindex myfile.aux   OR  > makeindex myfile.tex
  > make pdf myfile.tex

Comment: it's "like" `makeindex myfile`, and let `makeindex` work out what to do.  (actually remembering what tetex 3 has -- and what it hasn't -- is pretty difficult; i have a copy at home, but it hardly ever gets used.  i'm pretty sure it has `makeindex`, though.)

Comment: @Herbert :   It worked for me . Thanks a LOOOTTT!!!!

Comment: @wasteofspace : Thanks for your suggestion. but I think makeidx and makeindex just worked for me.

Comment: @knowit09: fine. I copied the command to an answer then it is not an open question.

Comment: Does this mean that the option in =\documentclass[makeidx]{book}= is useless?

Answer (score 8):

try `\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex` in the preamble of your document. you have also to run the external program `makeindex` and then `pdflatex` again.

Comment: Or load `\usepackage{ìmakeidx}\makeindex` and you don't need any external program call.

Comment: true, but `-shell-escape` ...

Comment: If you use the compiler `makeindex` you don't need `--shell-escape`. Only `Xindy` needs.

Answer (score 1):

`\makeindex` and `\index{}` are standard (La?)TeX, and not part of the package makeidx, only `\printindex` is.

So if you miss adding `\usepackage{makeidx}` to your preamble, you only get an error message at the point where you want to actually print the index, not before. This is a bit confusing.